# Generate Signed URL using Php & Nginx

Tags: php, security, nginx, pre-signed-url

I want to serve secure images with secure links to my users so that only authorized users have access to those links and media. Secure links for the stuff like images, videos etc uploaded by the users to my website.

When searching for some solutions, I came across **`Signed URLs`** used by many websites like Facebook, Google, Amazon etc for their secure images.

One of such url from Facebook is like

```
https://scontent.fkhi5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/86631274_1071501509854650_3164021107527254016_o.jpg?_nc_cat=109&_nc_eui2=AeEbeH9vDaeedhoklhnoAeDVl1BvS8e0JFyeaRHcgP_4xbo4hRYHO-tpuPUbLnDUS944GKxPE1xTIHwciOfeLL8XpxxayZnxePwIQFq4fZpr_g&_nc_ohc=MdMc7s30TXAAX8S9-fi&_nc_ht=scontent.fkhi5-1.fna&oh=a2df7628f8f8645f050be7ab52b3639a&oe=5EBA0586
```

As this is long **`Signed URLs`** with timestamp and even a single character is changed, the url becomes useless.

I tried to google some article for **`Signed URLs`** but all I could find was AWS, S3 and other CDN services etc and not any particular tutorial on how to generate such Signed URLs for my own website.

So, my question is **What Techniques I can use to generate `Signed URLs`  and how can use them to access on my website and show to authorized users only?**

Also is there any other better way to protect links and images other than **`Signed URLs`**? Any tutorial or code would be a great help.

Please note that this question is not about how to secure images but how to generate **`Signed URLs`**

Comment: I'd go like that: 1.Create: store data in db, create an identifier for the record, append identifier to url, 2. Read: read identifier from url, look up in db, load the requested data - Hashids would be useful here

Comment: @B001ᛦ So, that way I will have to query database each time to check if the url identifier is valid or not. If that's the case then I think it will be a little over load over server.

Comment: Sure, but how else should you store the related data? Youtube for example  is using hashids which get translated to numeric ids, those are stored in the database. I wouldn't be concerned about the performance of the database as stored values are integers, so no problem for a dbms e.g. mysql

Comment: You should first of all clarify, what _exactly_ you want to achieve. That example Facebook URL you posted, works for me as well - so it is clearly not directly tied to a specific user. So what _do_ you actually want?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _specific_ programming problems. This question is far too open-ended and conversational and needs refining in scope.

Comment: If you don’t want to have to look any data up in a database, then you can also put parameters (like a timestamp, until which the URL should be valid) into the URL directly - and protect it against manipulation, by hashing that data plus a secret value, and then adding the hash to the URL as well. Then you can check on the receiving end, whether the parameters you put in in “clear” form, give the same hash again when combined with your secret.

Comment: @misorude The URL i have posted is to show that along with the image name there is some kind of timestamp signature which if changed even a single character gets invalid. So, what's the technique

Comment: Well, likely one of the two different approaches that have been explained by now.

Comment: You can use the identifier anywhere in your url, it can be the filename or even the whole url --> `website.tld/identifier`

Comment: @misorude that seems a good technique. Can you please write some sample url and mention different parts in it. According to your logic, will my url be like this **http(s)://mysite/<my_image_name.jpg>?<timestamp><some_secret_hashed_data>**. Is that correct or anything else?

Comment: Take a look at [`ngx_http_secure_link`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_secure_link_module.html) module.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thanks alot Ivan. That is exactly what I was looking for. It really helped alot.